# ¿Cómo puedo comprimir archivos que tengo en un paquete de java?

Tags: java, netbeans, zip

estoy haciendo un proyecto y necesito ayuda con un tema.

Necesito comprimir unos archivos PDF que tengo dentro de la carpeta del proyecto, pero necesito que el procedimiento NO se haga con la ruta del computador (ya saben el C:\Documents\Netbeans Projects\ ....) sino que se haga internamente de forma que si se copie en otro computador funcione también.

Así es como lo tengo ahora:

```
package createpdf;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class ZipUtils {

    private List<String> fileList;
    private static final String OUTPUT_ZIP_FILE = "C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\Folder.zip";
    private static final String SOURCE_FOLDER = "C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\Comprimir"; // SourceFolder path

    public ZipUtils() {
        fileList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZipUtils appZip = new ZipUtils();
        appZip.generateFileList(new File(SOURCE_FOLDER));
        appZip.zipIt(OUTPUT_ZIP_FILE);
    }

    public void zipIt(String zipFile) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        String source = new File(SOURCE_FOLDER).getName();
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ZipOutputStream zos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
            zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

            System.out.println("Output to Zip : " + zipFile);
            FileInputStream in = null;

            for (String file : this.fileList) {
                System.out.println("File Added : " + file);
                ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(source + File.separator + file);
                zos.putNextEntry(ze);
                try {
                    in = new FileInputStream(SOURCE_FOLDER + File.separator + file);
                    int len;
                    while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                    }
                } finally {
                    in.close();
                }
            }

            zos.closeEntry();
            System.out.println("Folder successfully compressed");

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                zos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void generateFileList(File node) {
        // add file only
        if (node.isFile()) {
            fileList.add(generateZipEntry(node.toString()));
        }

        if (node.isDirectory()) {
            String[] subNote = node.list();
            for (String filename : subNote) {
                generateFileList(new File(node, filename));
            }
        }
    }

    private String generateZipEntry(String file) {
        return file.substring(SOURCE_FOLDER.length() + 1, file.length());
    }
}
```

**Como pueden ver, actualmente estoy accediendo a las carpetas de mi computador con:**
private static final String OUTPUT_ZIP_FILE = "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Folder.zip";
private static final String SOURCE_FOLDER = "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Comprimir"; //

**Pero necesito poder acceder internamente en el proyecto.**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Primero de todo hay que tener en cuenta 2 cosas, primero: 
Ahora mismo en tu código estas usando lo que se llama "Path Absoluto" es decir, toda la ruta del archivo des del disco en este caso el disco C. Normalmente mas recomendable trabajar con "Path Relativo" lo que significa la ruta del archivo des de donde estás acualmente hasta el archivo. Eso permite que funcione en cualquier computadora.

Para declarar un "Path Relativo" hay que hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
File file = new File("../pdfs/ejemplo1.pdf");  //manera correcta
```

.. significa retroceder un directorio des de donde te encuentras es decir si el Main.java esta en:  source/createpdf/ al retroceder significa que iremos hasta source/

después desde source avanzamos hasta source/pdfs/ y ahí encuentras los archivos.

Segundo: Las rutas de tus archivos los tienes el el escritorio, normalmente suele ser mal sitio donde tener los ficheros. Es recomendable tenerlos dentro de la carpeta de tu proyecto. Te recomendaria poner los ficheros dentro de la carpeta del proyecto, ya que para obtener el path relativo, también debes saber donde está ubicado tu proyecto. En caso de que lo tengas en documentos/netbeans projects(donde los ubica netbeans por defecto) tendrías que hacer lo siguiente:

File file = new File("../../../Desktop/Folder.zip");

Así llegarías des de NetBeans Projects hasta el escritorio. Recalco que esto no es una buena opción ya que depende de la versión del ordenador puede poner Desktop o bien Escritorio y entonces la ruta fallaria. Lo correcto seria poner los archivos dentro del proyecto igual como tienes hecho con ejemplo1.pdf y ejemplo2.pdf y puedes obtener su ruta relativa muy facilmente como te indico arriba.